# Certbot update caused cryptography error

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, certbot

I did an upgrade of my Ubuntu Bionic server and certbot fails now with:

```
certbot
An unexpected error occurred:
ContextualVersionConflict: (cryptography 2.1.4 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('cryptography>=2.3'), set(['PyOpenSSL']))
```

I can't seem to fix it no matter what I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to updated cryptograpy package

```
pip install cryptography --upgrade
```

Also it looks like current version is [2.7](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography)

Comment: And for those who have issues installing `cryptography` with the error `ffi.h`, you need to install `libffi-dev`